# How to display Swedish characters in a CSS file in a browser

Tags: html, css, browser, utf-8

I have an assignment in which I have to style an html document using CSS. The comments in the CSS file are in Swedish and when the CSS file is displayed in a browser the Swedish characters get scrambled. So I added "@charset "UTF-8";" to the beginning of my CSS file and that fixed the problem when I view the file in a browser locally. But part of the assignment is to upload the CSS file on to a server so it can be corrected. Once I upload it to the server and try to view it in the browser its back to a scrambled mess.

Comment: Are you sure css is at fault? Are you adding some text using `:before { content: 'some text'}` or `:after { content: 'sometext' }`?

Comment: try latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try on your CSS file

```
latin1_swedish_ci
```

Replace UTF-8 with this one. Also you can use a general one on your HTML

```
<meta charset="character_set">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion that it is a browser issue. Curiously, Firefox displays the Swedish characters of a CSS file even without using @charset "UTF-8" when opened locally but not when opened from my uni server, even with the @charset "UTF-8". Chrome requires the added @charset "UTF-8" to display the Swedish characters when opened locally which also works when opened from the server.